# SFX /Music settings from settings view and game view should match each other BOOL values

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to connect the SFX and Audio buttons on my settings view with the SFX and Audio buttons on my game view but I'm encountered some issues.

the issues are

*The button settings in the settings view should be ON by default when the user for the first time decides to play the game but will be saved as soon as he chooses to change them to what ever he/she chooses to set them to... so the next time the player returns to the settings no matter if its after the game ends manually by the player, terminates or enters in the background due to a phonecall etc, they should still be the once the player chose to have them on.

*the button settings on the game view should match the once in the settings view and should be saved if the player chooses to change them. So the next time the player enters the settings view they should be the once he chose to have inside the game.

I haven't managed so far to get this to work

I have a singleton class that handles the audio of the game  and then I have a implementation file that handles the settings as well as the game itself.

here's how I created the audio settings for both the settings view and the game view.

the first part is the settings code

```
-(IBAction)options{
    saveBackAudioON = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kSaveBackAudioON];

    saveSFXAudioON = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kSaveSFXAudioON];

    NSLog(@"Options");
    OptionsHeadtitle.hidden = NO;
    Start.hidden = YES;
    option.hidden = YES;
    howtoplay.hidden = YES;
    filter.hidden = NO;

    SFXimage.hidden = NO; 
    Musicimage.hidden = NO; 

    credits.hidden = NO;
    back.hidden = NO;
    newgame.hidden = YES;
    continuegame.hidden = YES;

    [self SFXswap];
    [self MUSICswap];   
}
-(IBAction)SFXswap{
    BOOL buttonstate = [SingletonSoundManager isSFXOn];
    [SingletonSoundManager setSFXOn:!buttonstate];

    if(buttonstate){
        NSLog(@"SFX Stops");
        sfx1.hidden = buttonstate;
        sfx2.hidden = !buttonstate;
    }
    else if(!buttonstate){
        NSLog(@"SFX Starts");
        sfx1.hidden = buttonstate;
        sfx2.hidden = !buttonstate;
    }   
}
-(IBAction)MUSICswap{
    BOOL buttonstate = [SingletonSoundManager isMusicOn];
    [SingletonSoundManager setMusicOn:!buttonstate]; 

    if(buttonstate){
        NSLog(@"Music Stops");
        music1.hidden = buttonstate;
        music2.hidden = !buttonstate;
    }
    else if(!buttonstate){
        NSLog(@"Music Starts");
        music1.hidden = buttonstate;
        music2.hidden =!buttonstate;
    }   
}
```

and this part is the settings inside the game view

```
    -(void)begingame{


    Pause.enabled = YES;
    musicbutton1.enabled = YES;
    musicbutton2.enabled = YES;
    sfxbutton1.enabled = YES;
    sfxbutton2.enabled = YES;

    Clock.hidden = NO;

    Pause.hidden = NO;

    totalSeconds = 300; //for 5 minutes 

    //Countdown for ongoing game
    countdowntimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(clockcountdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    //If music is on the play background music
    BOOL BackgroundMusicbuttonstate = [SingletonSoundManager isMusicOn];
    [SingletonSoundManager setMusicOn:!BackgroundMusicbuttonstate]; 

    //show which state the audio is on, if it´s enabled or disabled from the beginning
    if(!BackgroundMusicbuttonstate){
        musicbutton1.hidden = BackgroundMusicbuttonstate;
        musicbutton2.hidden = !BackgroundMusicbuttonstate;

    }

    //Play background music if the music is enabled from the beginning
    //if(musicbutton1.hidden == NO && musicbutton2.hidden == YES){  
    if(musicbutton1.hidden == NO){
        [sharedSoundManager playMusicWithKey:@"Background" timesToRepeat:-1];
        newGame = YES;
    }   
    //else if(musicbutton1.hidden == YES && music2.hidden == NO){
    else{

        [sharedSoundManager pausePlayingMusic];
    }

    BOOL SFXbuttonstate = [SingletonSoundManager isSFXOn];
    [SingletonSoundManager setSFXOn:!SFXbuttonstate]; 

    //show which state the SFX is on, if it´s enabled or disabled from the beginning
    if(!SFXbuttonstate){
        sfx1.hidden = SFXbuttonstate;
        sfx2.hidden = !SFXbuttonstate;

    }

    //Play SFX if SFX is enabled from the beginning
    if(SFXbuttonstate){     
        newGame = YES;
    }

    if(sfxbutton2.hidden == NO){
        [sharedSoundManager stopPlayingSFX];
    }   

    newGame = NO;
    isbrickdissapearing = NO;

    rubin1.center = CGPointMake(rubin2.center.x, rubin2.center.y);

    [self.view addSubview:rubin1];

}
-(IBAction)SFX{

    BOOL buttonstate = [SingletonSoundManager isSFXOn];
    [SingletonSoundManager setSFXOn:!buttonstate];

    if(buttonstate){
        NSLog(@"SFX Stops");
        sfxbutton1.hidden = buttonstate;
        sfxbutton2.hidden = !buttonstate;
    }
    else if(!buttonstate){
        NSLog(@"SFX Starts");
        sfxbutton1.hidden = buttonstate;
        sfxbutton2.hidden = !buttonstate;
    }


}

-(IBAction)MUSIC{

    BOOL buttonstate = [SingletonSoundManager isMusicOn];
    [SingletonSoundManager setMusicOn:!buttonstate]; 

    if(buttonstate){
        NSLog(@"Music Stops");
        musicbutton1.hidden = buttonstate;
        musicbutton2.hidden = !buttonstate;
        [sharedSoundManager pausePlayingMusic];

    }
    else if(!buttonstate){
        NSLog(@"Music Starts");
        musicbutton1.hidden = buttonstate;
        musicbutton2.hidden = !buttonstate;

        [sharedSoundManager resumePlayingMusic];

    }


}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that to save something to NSUserDefaults, you have to use something like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!previousValue forKey:@"soundOn"];
//  NSLog(@"mainPadOptions.mainOptions: %@", mainPadOptions.mainOptions);
[prefs synchronize];
```

Make sure that you synchronize the prefs when you want to be able to use them somewhere else.

I'd synchronize the preferences every time I changed views (or more often).

Then, when you want to change the sound value / button value, load the boolean like so:

```
BOOL soundFXOn = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"soundOn"] boolValue];
```

If you understand that, then you should have access to the correct boolean value. Should be cake to figure out from there.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick response. I tried that as well but then I get the game to crash instead :(

Comment: Can you post the function that caused it to crash? The part before all the mumbo jumbo that will say something along the lines of unrecognized selector. Also, note that I wrapped the boolean in an NSNumber, which you don't have to do. Just make sure you use setBoolFor key, not setObjectFor key.